# How to find horizontal tangent line with two variables?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given the equation $$2y^3+y^2-y^5=x^4-2x^3+x^2$$ I have to find the x-values for which the slope of the tangent line is equal to 0 (horizontal).
I derived the equation... $$(4x^3-6x^2+2x)\over(6y^2+2y-5y^4)$$
...but while with an equation with one variable, I would set the equation equal to 0 and solve for x, I don't know what to do with two variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $$y'=\frac{(4x^3-6x^2+2x)}{(6y^2+2y-5y^4)}$$
then  $$y'=0$$ if and only if

$$4x^3-6x^2+2x=0$$

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer, but can you explain why the numerator is set equal to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You have a good start: You have done the implicit differentiation, and the "equation" you present is the the correct expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Now for that to be zero, when the denominator is not infinite, you need to solve
$$
4x^3 -6x^2 +2x = 0$$
which gives $x=0$, $x=1$ and $x=1/2$.

Finally, you have to check that the $y$ values make sense for these $x$ values. 
$x=1$ and $x=1/2$ are obviously fine answers.

For $x=0$ you have 
$$
2 y^3 + y^2 - y^5 = 0
$$
The 
The solution $y=0$ is problematic, since the derivative at that point is potentially undefined. The other two solutions are  $y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and those are two fine points on the curve, so $x=0$ is a good answer.

The set of $x$ values is $\left\{ 1, 1/2, 1\right\}$